# Как увеличить границы div

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Разметка элементов происходит с помощью flex.
Я хочу увеличить границы блока в котором сейчас находится информация о пользователе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался с помощью padding
Оно увеличилось, но сам блок не по центру смещен в бок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На блок-родитель блока с контентом добавить "justify-content: center".

Comment: возможно, вам так же поможет ещё то, что лучше все задавать в процентах, а не пикселях. тогда это будет а) легко отображаемо как надо, б) адаптируемо сразу под другие платформы.